# svg image not visible after reload

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I'm trying to draw svg(circle) on the mouse coords when I click the mouse.
When the page was first loaded, a circle was printed.
But after refreshing, coordinates are output in the log, but images are not display, when I clicked the mouse.

what is wrong with my code ... ?

```
import React from "react";
import { select, pointer } from "d3";

const CircleSvg = () => {
const svg = select("#circleSvg")

const onSvgClick= (e) => { 
  const coords = pointer(e, this);
  console.log(coords);
  drawCircle(coords[0], coords[1]);
};

function drawCircle(x, y) {
  svg
    .append("circle")
    .join("circle")
    .attr("cx", x)
    .attr("cy", y)
    .attr("r", 10)
    .attr("fill", "black");

  console.log(x, y);
  console.log(svg);
}

return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <svg id="circleSvg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" onClick=. {onSvgClick}>
      <circle />
  </svg>
</React.Fragment>
);
};

export default CircleSvg;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're bypassing React's render call (return value from your `CircleSvg` component) to add `<circle>`s to the SVG.

When `d3.select('#circleSvg')` is run, React might not have rendered the `<svg>` yet. If the `<svg>` isn't rendered yet, you might get an empty d3 selection. That is what's happening upon reload in your code. Your code might work **sometimes**, when React renders the `<svg>` before the `d3.select()` is called and the selection is not empty. Check the output of `console.log(svg._groups[0][0])` in the console. If it's `null`, your clicks won't create any circles. (You can check [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-water-2czc09?file=/src/CircleSvgOld.js:129-199) )

There could be two approaches to fix this.

1. Let React handle all the rendering and use D3 only for finding the click position. On every click, store the coordinates using `useState` hook. (see `CircleSvgNew.js` in this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-water-2czc09?file=/src/CircleSvgNew.js))
2. Do any changes to the DOM you do outside of React's render after the render is done. The [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook can be utilised to achieve that. (see `CircleSvgD3.js` in this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-water-2czc09?file=/src/CircleSvgD3.js), same sandbox as above, different file)